# SQL Server 2016 HA Options for thousand databases

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, high-availability

Currently we have a 4 node Active\Active\Active\Active Windows\SQL Server 2008r2(ENT Edition) cluster that we need to upgrade to Win2012r2\SQL Server 2016.

- We have over a thousand databases, and growing, on the cluster (100mb -> 1tb) and development is rolling out an API that will require read only copies of each database.
- Business ultimately wants to go to Azure (mid 2018 time frame)
- Budget wants us to use STD Edition
- Systems wants us to virtualize (Current Servers are physical 80
  core\512gb RAM each)
- DR is log shipping

I'm thinking of using Availability groups but for the read only secondary requirement it requires ENT Edition and the over a thousand DBs makes it a budget buster.

I was also thinking instead of AGs, using replication, but peer to peer is a monster to use with agile development. Individual publishing of a thousand databases is a lot to manage. Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: You mention you want to go to Azure mid-2018, so why not start planning for that now as part of your need to move to Win2012R2/SQL2016? Assuming you are not going to be moving to a 100% cloud based environment, then azure can participate in your availability groups to give you your read-only replicas?

Comment: So the migration plan for Azure is any new databases are setup on Azure and we trickle the current databases so as not to have too much of an impact on clients.. We are a SaaS and downtime is a concern. Also it will take our development team a year to change over to a PaaS implementation. So Azure needs to be considered but is not the immediate need. The API is the main concern.

Comment: One of your requirements has to give way to reality.  Given the historical purchase of Enterprise, I would say that it's probably going to be the budget guys.  You could probably save some money by doing an analysis to see if you really need 80 cores worth of SQL Server.  More memory might offset fewer cores as well, but Standard only supports 128 GB.  Is it possible to tier your clients?